# How to extract revert message from this specific object?

Tags: web3js, transactions, error

I have the follow error object that was caught in a catch statement

```
Error: execution reverted: Auction owner is not authorized
{
  "originalError": {
    "code": 3,
    "data": "0x08c379a00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001f41756374696f6e206f776e6572206973206e6f7420617574686f72697a656400",
    "message": "execution reverted: Auction owner is not authorized"
  }
}
```

This error message was generated from this call to a smart contract instance, performed as the following

```
endAuction = async () => {

        try{ 

        const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
            //Create new instance of plastic bale SC that has been deployed 
            const plasticBaleSC = plasticBaleContract(this.props.address);
            await plasticBaleSC.methods.endAuction().call();  

            this.setState({notOver: false});
        } catch (err){
            console.log(err.originalError);
        }


    };
```

How can I extract message from that error object? I tried `err.originalError.message` and `err.message` but both methods failed.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue and I noticed that this

```
Error: execution reverted: Auction owner is not authorized
{
  "originalError": {
    "code": 3,
    "data": "0x08c379a00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001f41756374696f6e206f776e6572206973206e6f7420617574686f72697a656400",
    "message": "execution reverted: Auction owner is not authorized"
  }
}
```

is the error message.

So in order to extract the additional info, you may use

```
const jsonStr = e.message.substr(e.message.indexOf('{'));
const json = JSON.parse(jsonStr);
```

Gives you the actual object.
You can then access it with `json.originalError.code` or whatever.